# ¿Por que esta operación matemática(multiplicatoria) me devuelve 0 siempre? [C]

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
pim = 1;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    pim *= (2*i/(2*i-1))*(2*i/(2*i+1));
}
```

al imprimir pim me devuelve 0.0000... (i y n son int, pim es float).

no importa el valor que le de a n siempre retorna 0

Comment: ¿Qué significa este número?1.5707962875412396, 1.57079632433165

Comment: Ah, es pi/2, qué bueno que estás intentando calcular pi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La división con ints es lo que en matemática se denomina una `división entera por defecto`.

Entonces, como en el factor `(2*i/(2*i+1))` para i > 0, el divisor es siempre mayor que el dividendo, el cociente será siempre 0. Y el producto de dos factores donde al menos uno de ellos es cero, también será 0.

Comment: gracias me e confundido con otros lenguajes y me e quedado bastante desconcertado cuando paso esto.